# Accessing tabs + adding content to them

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is probably a stupid question, but I'm really new to HTML. Anyway, if I have a bunch of tabs [like so](http://www.bootply.com/KRj6eJU06O), how do I make it so that the user can actually access these tabs when clicking on them and see their content? Not to mention, how do I give them content in the first place, as I've tried to follow the naming conventions that many tutorials use, but for some reason, that doesn't work with what I have.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you not used Bootstrap?

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.bootply.com/BBgCDRQiAp

Here's what you need to do:

**html**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container">

                    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="navtab" role="tablist">

                            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" role="tab">Tab1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#tab2" role="tab">Tab2</a></li>

                            <li class="dropdown">   
                                <a href="#tab3" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span>Tab3</span><b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#subtab1" role="tab">Subtab1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#subtab2" role="tab">Subtab2</a></li>
                                </ul><!-- END: "dropdown-menu" -->      
                            </li><!-- END: "dropdown" -->
                            <li><a href="#tab4">Tab4</a></li>

                        </ul><!-- END: "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" -->

                    </div><!-- END: "container" -->
                </div><!-- END: "container" -->
            </div><!-- END: "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" -->

<br/><br/><br/>

<div class="tab-content"> <!-- HERE GOES YOUR TAB CONTENTS -->

  <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">The <h1>tab1</h1> content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">The tab2 content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="subtab1">The subtab1 content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="subtab2">The subtab2 content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">The tab4 content</div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$('#navtab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

**Reference:**

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-examples

Comment: Thank you. I see where my problem was. If I have pre-existing content on my initial page, like a jumbotron, how do I clear that when I click on a tab so that it only shows that tab's content?

Comment: You can hide it. $('#jumbotronDivId').hide(); call this when you show tab content